# Selecting the p tag within a div with an id, using a sibling h3 tag with a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Apologies if the title above is a little convoluted, writing these things in plain English is often more difficult than the problem within!

I'm sure this is a fairly basic issue but I'm getting a bit tied up with jQuery selectors and hierachy and can't see the wood for the trees now...it's a classroom exercise so I'm stuck with the HTML code as it is.

I'm trying to hide/display the paragraphs underneath a H3 heading by double clicking the H3 heading.

```
<div class="chapter" id="chapter-preface">
    <h3 class="chapter-title">Preface</h3>
    <p>Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah</p>
    <p>Blah, blah, blah, blah</p>
    <p>Blah, blah, blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
</div>
<div class="chapter" id="chapter-1">
    <h3 class="chapter-title">Chapter 1</h3>
    <p>Rhubarb, rhubarb, rhubarb, rhubarb, rhubarb, rhubarb</p>
    <p>Rhubarb, rhubarb, rhubarb</p>
</div>
```

The closest I've come so far is the following jQuery code:

```
$('.chapter-title').dblclick(function() {
    $('div p').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

but as is probably fairly evident this only has the effect of hiding all p tags under both of the divs. I want it to just hide the p tags under the relevant H3 heading that was double clicked. I've tried using 'this' but evidently incorrectly as it didn't have the desired effect.

I guess I need to somehow select the parent div of the H3 tag clicked on and the unique id associated with it and then apply the hide/display event to any child p tags within....any suggestions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) or [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) to pick all the `p` elements following that `h3` in the parent `div`, without actually selecting the parent `div`:

```
$('.chapter-title').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('p').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: I *would* select the parent `div` and give it the class, then apply the hidden styles to `div.chapter.hidden p` instead, as a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.chapter-title').dblclick(function() {
   $(this).siblings('p').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `nextAll('p')` will get all the elements following the current with the matching selector. `toggle()` will then hide/show them as required, and saves the use of your class.

Try this:

```
$('.chapter-title').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('p').toggle();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qL32d/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.nextAll` or `.siblings`:

```
$('.chapter-title').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).nextAll("p").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

or:

```
$('.chapter-title').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).siblings("p").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't  simply use `toggle()`  **instead of** *toggleClass('hidden')*  and in your case you have only para elements inside your div,so you can again simply write `siblings()` .but if you have other elements ,then ofcourse *siblings('p')*  is a way to go.

Here is the code

```
 $('.chapter-title').dblclick(function() {
$(this).siblings().toggle(); 
});
```

Just if you need to know more :

**working**---When any of the heading  is clicked this  modifies the CSS property `display:inline` to `display:hidden` and when the title is  clicked  again this CSS property  changes  back to `display:inline` . yeah ! it restores it .